# Writing JS varibales to functions and content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating some JS that will detect the URL and assign variables based on the current path.

The script will then write the variables to functions and other scripts on the page.

Im pretty new to JS and having issues actually getting the variables into the other places.

I can alert the variables but not sure how to get them to be added to the other scripts.

Script so far.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>

//define deafult id's and tags
var defaultBotID = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
var defaultBotAdTag = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";

//define id's and tags for xxx section
var anotherBotID = "aaaaaaaaaaaa";
var anotherBotAdTag = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb";

//define the variables to be used on the page
window.adBotID;
window.adBotTag;


//**************************
// Check the current URL then assign id's and tags
if (window.location.href.indexOf("xxxx") > -1) {
            adBotID = anotherBotID;
            adBotTag = anotherBotAdTag;
    }  else {
            adBotID = defaultBotID;
            adBotTag = defaultBotAdTag;
    } 
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
googletag.defineSlot('**NEED ADBOTTAG HERE**', [300, 250], '**NEED ADBOTID HERE**').addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
googletag.enableServices();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id='**NEED ADBOTID HERE**' style='width:300px; height:250px;'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('**NEED ADBOTID HERE**'); });
</script>
</div>

</body>
```

I have added the locations where i need the variables to be written.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `defineSlot(adBotTag, [300, 250], adBotID)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the variables you need to access defined on window, you can also access them via window.

```
googletag.defineSlot(window.adBotTag, [300, 250], window.adBotID).addService(googletag.pubads());
```

and

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display(window.adBotID); });
```